# Buffer is not defined, after migrating from CRA(create react app) to vite

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vite, cra

After having declared and done all the config files, when I start the server I get Buffer not defined and the error points to an npm module.
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not definedat node_modules/jsesc/jsesc.js`

Comment: I am having the exact same problem (on vite 2.6.14 and plugin-react 1.1.3). 
Any luck in finding the solution ?

Comment: @flieks
I wrote this in vite.config.js
defineConfig({
define: {
    **"Buffer": {},**
.....
This way I managed to get the error away but still not sure if it's the right thing to do because I still cannot test the app as I have another problem to deal with which is "Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility and cannot be accessed in client code"

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I'm having the exact same problem rn.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following changes to fix the issue,
in vite.config.ts , index.html and adding packages

**1.Install Packages**

```
yarn add process util buffer events
yarn add @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill
```

**2.Update vite.config**

```
import GlobalPolyFill from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { resolve } from "path";
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            define: {
                global: "globalThis",
            },
            plugins: [
                GlobalPolyFill({
                    process: true,
                    buffer: true,
                }),
            ],
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            process: "process/browser",
            stream: "stream-browserify",
            zlib: "browserify-zlib",
            util: "util",
        },
    },
});
```

**3.Update index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/src/assets/images/favicon.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Vite App</title>
  <script>
    window.global = window;
  </script>
  <script type="module">
    import process from "process";
    import EventEmitter from "events";
    import {Buffer} from "buffer";
    window.Buffer = Buffer;
    window.process = process;
    window.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="module" src="./src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```